# Serial port ReadFile reads 0 bytes and returns true

Tags: c, windows, winapi, serial-port, initialization

I'm trying to read in data from a serial port in Windows 7 using the Windows API. When I try to read in data, the `WaitCommEvent()` fires just fine and the `ReadFile()` call returns 1 as the status, but no data is read in. In the the [ReadFile documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx) it says that:

> When a synchronous read operation reaches the end of a file, `ReadFile` returns `TRUE` and sets `*lpNumberOfBytesRead` to zero.

However, I'm sure there are no `EOT` characters in the data being sent over the serial port.

I currently have two USB cables plugged into my computer and connected to each other. I know that they can send and receive data as I have tested them with Putty.

Why won't `ReadFile()` read in any data?

My code is below.

Header:

```
typedef struct uart_handle
{
   uint8_t port_num;
   char port_name[10];
   uint32_t baud_rate;
   uint8_t byte_size;
   uint8_t stop;
   uint8_t parity;
   int32_t error;
   HANDLE handle;
} uart_handle;
```

Main file:

```
uart_handle* serial_comm_init(uint8_t port_num, uint32_t baud_rate, uint8_t byte_size, uint8_t stop, uint8_t parity)
{
   uart_handle*  uart;
   DCB           uart_params = { 0 };
   COMMTIMEOUTS  timeouts    = { 0 };
   int           status;

   uart         = (uart_handle*) malloc(1 * sizeof(uart_handle));
   status       = 0;

   // Set port name
   if (port_num > 9)
   {
      sprintf(uart->port_name, "\\\\.\\COM%d", port_num);
   }
   else
   {
      sprintf(uart->port_name, "COM%d", port_num);
   }

   // Set baud rate
   uart->baud_rate = baud_rate;

   // Set byte size
   uart->byte_size = byte_size;

   // Set stop bit
   uart->stop = stop;

   // Set parity
   uart->parity = parity;

   // Set up comm state
   uart_params.DCBlength = sizeof(uart_params);
   status = GetCommState(uart->handle, &uart_params);
   uart_params.BaudRate = uart->baud_rate;
   uart_params.ByteSize = uart->byte_size;
   uart_params.StopBits = uart->stop;
   uart_params.Parity   = uart->parity;
   SetCommState(uart->handle, &uart_params);

   // Setup actual file handle
   uart->handle = CreateFile(uart->port_name, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
   if (uart->handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
      printf("Error opening serial port %s.\n", uart->port_name);
      free(uart);
      return NULL;
   }
   else {
      printf("Serial port %s opened successfully.\n", uart->port_name);
   }

   // Set timeouts
   status = GetCommTimeouts(uart->handle, &timeouts);
   timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout         = 50;
   timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant    = 50;
   timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier  = 10;
   timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant   = 50;
   timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
   status = SetCommTimeouts(uart->handle, &timeouts);
   if (status == 0) {
      printf("Error setting comm timeouts: %d", GetLastError());
   }

   return uart;
}

int32_t serial_comm_read(void* handle, uint8_t* msg, uint32_t msg_size, uint32_t timeout_ms, uint32_t flag)
{
   uart_handle*  uart;
   uint32_t      num_bytes_read;
   uint32_t      event_mask;
   int32_t       status;

   uart            = (uart_handle*) handle;
   num_bytes_read  = 0;
   event_mask      = 0;
   status          = 0;

   memset(msg, 0, msg_size);

   // Register Event
   status = SetCommMask(uart->handle, EV_RXCHAR);

   // Wait for event
   status = WaitCommEvent(uart->handle, &event_mask, NULL);

   printf("Recieved characters.\n");

   do {
      status = ReadFile(uart->handle, msg, msg_size, &num_bytes_read, NULL);
      printf("Status: %d\n", status);
      printf("Num bytes read: %d\n", num_bytes_read);
      printf("Message: %s\n", msg);

   } while (num_bytes_read > 0);

   printf("Read finished.\n");

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Serial port COM9 opened successfully.
Recieved characters.
Status: 1
Num bytes read: 0
Message:
Read finished.
```

Comment: Are you sure `msg_size` is not 0 ?

Comment: Note: `port_num > 99` leads to overwriting `port_name[10]`.  Should be wider. `port_num` should be checked against 0.  Valid port numbers are 1-256.

Comment: Unclear about "I'm sure there are no EOF characters"  What is an EOF _character_?

Comment: @chux Didn't realize ports over 100 were valid. Thanks for the input

Comment: Without seeing the calling code, AFAIK, `msg == NULL;` The posted code lacks argument validation.  Many issues could be because of invalid calls, set-up.  Suggest adding defensive coding, if anything at least as `assert()`s.  It saves you time.

Comment: The code shown calls `GetCommState()` on an uninitialised handle: `... = GetCommState(uart->handle, &uart_params);` provoking UB doing so. It's returned status is not tested. Due to this `uart_params` probably contains BS.

Comment: OK, so assuming these basics and others (incorrectly using "%d" with int32_t) are not the issue, if code loops until `status == 0`, do you receive the expected input?

Comment: @alk That was it! Thanks :) Could you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code shown calls `GetCommState()` on an *uninitialised* handle:

```
status = GetCommState(uart->handle, &uart_params);
```

provoking UB doing so. Its returned status is not tested.

Due to this `uart_params` probably contains <strike>BS</strike> no useful data.

---

**Do yourself a favour:** *Always and ever check the return value on **all** relevant function calls (and let the code act accordingly)!* Consider as "relevant" all those functions returning or changing data used afterwards.